# Change delimiter on "for each" loops on Strings in python

Tags: python

I need to read an input text file in python, by streaming line by line. That means load the text file line by line instead of all at once into memory. But my line delimiters are not whitespaces, they are arbitrary characters.

Here is a method on Stack Overflow for loading files line by line:

```
with open("log.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        do_something_with(line)
```

The above is perfect, however I need to change the delimiter from whitespaces to a different character.

How can this be done? Thank you.

Comment: I do not follow.  Your line delimiters are not either `\r\n` or `\n`?

Comment: They are some arbitrary character, but not \r\n or \n or the tab character. So you are right

Comment: What character is it exactly? How large is the file?

Comment: It is the '#' character

Comment: A request for this feature has been around for a while, there's a recipe in here: http://bugs.python.org/issue1152248

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import re
def open_delimited(filename, delimiter, chunksize=1024, *args, **kwargs):
    with open(filename, *args, **kwargs) as infile:
        remainder = ''
        for chunk in iter(lambda: infile.read(chunksize), ''):
            pieces = re.split(delimiter, remainder+chunk)
            for piece in pieces[:-1]:
                yield piece
            remainder = pieces[-1]
        if remainder:
            yield remainder

for line in open_delimited("log.txt", delimiter='/'):
    print(repr(line))
```

Comment: Good use of `iter` with sentinel.

Comment: This is great, but I would add a way to change the chunksize in the arguments

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't have a native construct for this. You can write a generator that reads the characters one at a time and accumulates them until you have a whole delimited item.

```
def items(infile, delim):
    item = []
    c = infile.read(1)
    while c:
        if c == delim:
            yield "".join(item)
            item = []
        else:
            c = infile.read(1)
            item.append(c)
    yield "".join(item)

with open("log.txt") as infile:
    for item in items(infile, ","):   # comma delimited
        do_something_with(item)
```

You will get better performance if you read the file in chunks (say, 64K or so) and split these. However, the logic for this is more complicated since an item may be split across chunks, so I won't go into it here as I'm not 100% sure I'd get it right.  :-)