# python read blocks of lines from file

Tags: python, text-processing

i have a script from which i get the output (i also save this output to a file in f1 = 20141202.194812_carStatus/):

```
---------------------------------------------
TM 05120970.01: Processing...
TM 05120970: Processing...
TM 05120970: current status Open
TM 05120970: Owner_Info.User_ref = crossi14
TM 05120970: Owner_Info.Email = Criss.Rossi@gmail.com
TM 05120970: CarModel = Nissan Micra
----------------------------------------------
TM 05157414.06: Processing...
TM 05157414: Processing...
TM 05157414: current status Open
TM 05157414: Owner_Info.User_ref = yumiao12
TM 05157414: Owner_Info.Email = Yu.Miao@gmail.com
TM 05157414: CarModel = Toyota Avensis
----------------------------------------------
```

i used: `exec_cmd('cat ' + f1 + '| grep -e "CarModel = " -e "Owner_Info.User_ref = "')`
but i also need the first line (actually the second) of the block

```
TM 05157414.06: Processing...
```

what i try/need to do is, parse and and get the values in a variable for each of this blocks:

```
TM 05120970.01 -> car_number = 05120970.01

Owner_Info.User_ref = crossi14 -> owner_user = crossi14

CarModel = Nissan Micra -> car_model = Nissan Micra
```

with this information i will add some default things like:

```
priority = Unknown
```

and i will need to have this variables as input for another script called insert_owner_car.pl

```
 insert_owner_car.pl -id 05120970.01 -o owner_user="crossi14",car_model="Nissan Micra",priority="Unknown"
```

this is what i manage to do so far, but its not usuable as i cant get the mentioned values

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import itertools, commands, datetime, os, re, sys, time

inFile = open("/tmp/20141202.194812_carStatus")
outFile = open("result.txt", "w")
keepCurrentSet = False
for line in inFile:
    if line.startswith("----------------------------------------------"):
        keepCurrentSet = False
    if keepCurrentSet:
        parts = line.split(" = ")[1:]
        part=','.join(parts)
        print part
#outFile.write(parts)   
    if line.startswith("----------------------------------------------"):
        keepCurrentSet = True
inFile.close()
outFile.close()
```

i dont know how to get: 05120970.01
and how to have all the variables from one block to be able to use them as input for that other script

PS: i have python 2.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `re` module to extract relevant information : it is standard, easy and robust.
You could also display block information on a block limit and add a catch all at end of file.

The script would be :

```
import re

rnum = re.compile('\s*TM\s+([^\s:]+):.*')
ruser = re.compile('.*Owner_Info.User_ref\s*=\s*(.*)')
rmodel = re.compile('.*CarModel\s*=\s*(.*)')


def display(out, num, user, model):
    print(num, user, model)
    out.write('insert_owner_car.pl -id %s -o owner_user="%s",car_model="%s",priority="Unknown"\n' % (num, user, model))

inFile = open("/tmp/20141202.194812_carStatus")
outFile = open("result.txt", "w")
firstOfBlock = False
carnum = None
for line in inFile:
    if line.startswith("--------------------------------"):
        firstOfBlock = True
        if carnum is not None:
            display(outFile, carnum, user, model)
            carnum = None
    else:
        if firstOfBlock:
            m = rnum.match(line)
            if m is not None:
                carnum = m.group(1)
                firstOfBlock = False
        else:
            line = line.strip()
            m = ruser.match(line)
            if m is not None:
                user = m.group(1)
            else:
                m = rmodel.match(line)
                if m is not None:
                    model = m.group(1)

if carnum is not None:
    display(outFile, carnum, user, model)
    carnum = None

inFile.close()
outFile.close()
```

With your current example, output is

```
05120970.01 crossi14 Nissan Micra
05157414.06 yumiao12 Toyota Avensis
```

and result.txt is :

```
insert_owner_car.pl -id 05120970.01 -o owner_user="crossi14",car_model="Nissan Micra",priority="Unknown"
insert_owner_car.pl -id 05157414.06 -o owner_user="yumiao12",car_model="Toyota Avensis",priority="Unknown"
```

Comment: $ ./test11.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test11.py", line 25, in ?
    carnum = m.group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @KayNix : sorry I did a bad copy and paste. Fixed

Comment: thank you, it worked :D
now i want it to use a dictonary and group the carmodels into luxury, compact, small...but ill get back with that if i cant manage :D

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [utility function `open_chunk`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17508761/190597) to process the file in chunks:

```
import re
import subprocess

def open_chunk(readfunc, delimiter, chunksize=1024):
    """
    readfunc(chunksize) should return a string.
    """
    remainder = ''
    for chunk in iter(lambda: readfunc(chunksize), ''):
        pieces = re.split(delimiter, remainder + chunk)
        for piece in pieces[:-1]:
            yield piece
        remainder = pieces[-1]
    if remainder:
        yield remainder

f = open(filename, 'r')
for chunk in open_chunk(f.read, delimiter=r'-{45,}'):
    chunk = chunk.strip()
    if chunk:
        lines = chunk.splitlines()
        firstline = lines[0]
        car_number = firstline.split()[1][:-1]
        for line in lines[1:]:
            if 'Owner_Info.User_ref = ' in line:
                owner_user = line.split(" = ")[1]
            elif 'CarModel = ' in line:
                car_model =  line.split(" = ")[1]
        cmd = ['insert_owner_car.pl'
               , '-id'
               , car_number
               , '-o'
               , 'owner_user="%s"' % (owner_user, )
               , 'car_model="%s"' % (car_model, )
               , 'priority="Unknown"']
        print(' '.join(cmd))
        # subprocess.call(cmd)
f.close()
```

prints

```
insert_owner_car.pl -id 05120970.01 -o owner_user="crossi14" car_model="Nissan Micra" priority="Unknown"
insert_owner_car.pl -id 05157414.06 -o owner_user="yumiao12" car_model="Toyota Avensis" priority="Unknown"
```

---

If your data file is small, then you could slurp the entire file into a string and then use `re.split` to split it into chunks:

```
In [37]: import re

In [38]: re.split(r'-{45,}', open('data').read())
Out[38]: 
['\n\n',
 '\nTM 05120970.01: Processing...\nTM 05120970: Processing...\nTM 05120970: current status Open\nTM 05120970: Owner_Info.User_ref = crossi14\nTM 05120970: Owner_Info.Email = Criss.Rossi@gmail.com\nTM 05120970: CarModel = Nissan Micra\n',
 '\nTM 05157414.06: Processing...\nTM 05157414: Processing...\nTM 05157414: current status Open\nTM 05157414: Owner_Info.User_ref = yumiao12\nTM 05157414: Owner_Info.Email = Yu.Miao@gmail.com\nTM 05157414: CarModel = Toyota Avensis\n',
 '\n']
```

This could be used instead of `open_chunk`, above. The advantage of using `open_chunk` is that it can be used on very large files, when slurping the entire file into a string and splitting it into a list requires too much memory.

Comment: looks good, but i cant seam to be able to use the with open thing...
    File "./test8.py", line 20
        with open('data_file/tmp/20141202.194812_carStatus') as f:
            ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Oh, I forgot you are using Python2.5. To use a `with statement`, you need to add [`from __future__ import with_statement`](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-343-the-with-statement) to the top of the code. Here is an [explanation of the with-statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm).

Comment: yes, its still not working, i did:
from __future__ import with_statement
import re
import subprocess
import six

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full traceback error message.

Comment: same error, seams that the future stuff isnt doing what it should
$ ./test10.py
  File "./test10.py", line 21
    with open("/tmp/20141202.194812_carStatus", 'r') as f:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Did you put `from __future__ import with_statement` at the very top of the script, before all other import statements, but after `#!/usr/bin/python`?

Comment: yes, i did... no luck, then i tested this:
`import __future__
import sys
print __future__.all_feature_names`

output was: ['nested_scopes', 'generators', 'division']

Comment: Okay, then. I've edited the post to open the file without a `with-statement`.

Comment: thank you @unutbu, i now get the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test02.py", line 30, in ?
    cmd = ["crau"
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format'

Comment: Ugh, my mistake. I've changed the code to use `%` instead of `format`.

Comment: thank you, works as well, just a small carrection, its: f = open(filename, 'r')