# Groupby on chunks might lead to groups split between chunks

Tags: pandas

I have some humongous files I need to read in chunks due to their size.

I want to do a groupby and then a function on these files.

Problem is, if the chunksize is `50 000` and if a group exists at rows `49998-50002`, this group will be split into two; one group in the first chunk, another group in the second chunk. Is there a way to solve this problem of a group existing between chunks?

All solutions I could come up with feel rather `un-Pandaish` so perhaps I should just solve this problem by reading the table in two passes.

Comment: what values are you looking for in the `groupby`? can you just group the `groupby`'s together?

Comment: If you can't keep all the groupbys in memory, can you compare group keys between successive chunks, to handle split groups?(Logically yes, if you chunk to half the size you'd have been chunking to otherwise.)  (You're confident the groups are contiguous within the file? If so, there's probably an efficient version of chunking that doesn't break up groups, but I don't know that it exists: you might have to write it yourself.)

Comment: @acushner I guess, but all the ways I looked at of doing this was ugly (remember last group from previous chunk and compare it to first group of next chunk or similar.)

Comment: @cphlewis Yes, the files are sorted already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of no out-of-the-box function for this, but here is how you could roll your own:

```
remainder = pd.DataFrame()
for filename in filenames:                                            # 1
    for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=[0], chunksize=300): # 2 
        grouped = chunk.groupby(['group'])
        for grp, nextgrp in iwindow(grouped, 2):                      # 3
            group_num, df = grp                                       # 4
            if nextgrp is None:
                # When nextgrp is None, grp is the last group
                remainder = pd.concat([remainder, df])                # 5
                break                                                 # 6
            if len(remainder):                                        # 7
                df = pd.concat([remainder, df])
                remainder = pd.DataFrame()
            print(filename)
            process(df)                                               # 8
if len(remainder):                                                    # 9         
    process(remainder)
```

1. Obviously, we need to iterate over every file
2. Read the file in chunks. `chunksize=300` tells `read_csv` to read the file in chunks of 300 bytes. I made it small for the example below. You can increase this to read more of the file per iteration.
3. `iwindow` is a sliding window utility function. It returns the items in `grouped` two at a time. For example,

   ```
   In [117]: list(iwindow([1,2,3], 2))
   Out[117]: [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, None)]
   ```
4. `df` is a DataFrame with a constant `group` value (equal to `group_num`).
5. Don't process the last DataFrame because it might be a partial DataFrame with more coming in the next chunk. Save it in `remainder`.
6. Break out of the inner loop. Go on to the next chunk (if any).
7. If `remainder` holds some unprocessed DataFrame, prepend it to `df`
8. Finally, process `df`
9. `remainder` might hold one last unprocessed DataFrame. So process it now.

The general idea being employed here is useful whenever you need to read a file in chunks but process the chunks according to some other delimiter.
Essentially the [same idea is used here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17508761/190597) to break a file into chunks delimited by a regex pattern.

---

For example,

```
import itertools as IT
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def make_data(groupsize, ngroups, filenames):
    nfiles = len(filenames)
    group_num = np.repeat(np.arange(ngroups), groupsize) 
    arr = np.random.randint(10, size=(len(group_num), 2))
    arr = np.column_stack([group_num, arr])
    for arri, filename in zip(np.array_split(arr, nfiles), filenames):
        df = pd.DataFrame(arri, columns=['group','A','B'])
        df.to_csv(filename) 

def iwindow(iterable, n=2, fillvalue=None):
    """
    Returns a sliding window (of width n) over data from the sequence.
    s -> (s0,s1,...s[n-1]), (s1,s2,...,sn), ...
    """
    iterables = IT.tee(iterable, n)
    iterables = (IT.islice(it, pos, None) for pos, it in enumerate(iterables))
    for result in IT.izip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue=None):
        yield result

def process(df):
    print(df)
    print('-'*80)

filenames = ['/tmp/data-{}.csv'.format(i) for i in range(3)]
make_data(groupsize=40, ngroups=5, filenames=filenames)

remainder = pd.DataFrame()
for filename in filenames:
    for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=[0], chunksize=300):
        grouped = chunk.groupby(['group'])
        for grp, nextgrp in iwindow(grouped, 2):
            group_num, df = grp
            if nextgrp is None:
                # When nextgrp is None, grp is the last group
                remainder = pd.concat([remainder, df])
                break
            if len(remainder):
                df = pd.concat([remainder, df])
                remainder = pd.DataFrame()
            print(filename)
            process(df)
if len(remainder):
    process(remainder)
```

Comment: though note it's exactly the approach you feared was ugly -- "remember last group from previous chunk and compare it to first group of next chunk or similar".