# Unpacking tuple-like textfile

Tags: python, regex, list, tuples

Given a textfile of lines of 3-tuples:

```
(0, 12, Tokenization)
(13, 15, is)
(16, 22, widely)
(23, 31, regarded)
(32, 34, as)
(35, 36, a)
(37, 43, solved)
(44, 51, problem)
(52, 55, due)
(56, 58, to)
(59, 62, the)
(63, 67, high)
(68, 76, accuracy)
(77, 81, that)
(82, 91, rulebased)
(92, 102, tokenizers)
(103, 110, achieve)
(110, 111, .)

(0, 3, But)
(4, 14, rule-based)
(15, 25, tokenizers)
(26, 29, are)
(30, 34, hard)
(35, 37, to)
(38, 46, maintain)
(47, 50, and)
(51, 56, their)
(57, 62, rules)
(63, 71, language)
(72, 80, specific)
(80, 81, .)

(0, 2, We)
(3, 7, show)
(8, 12, that)
(13, 17, high)
(18, 26, accuracy)
(27, 31, word)
(32, 35, and)
(36, 44, sentence)
(45, 57, segmentation)
(58, 61, can)
(62, 64, be)
(65, 73, achieved)
(74, 76, by)
(77, 82, using)
(83, 93, supervised)
(94, 102, sequence)
(103, 111, labeling)
(112, 114, on)
(115, 118, the)
(119, 128, character)
(129, 134, level)
(135, 143, combined)
(144, 148, with)
(149, 161, unsupervised)
(162, 169, feature)
(170, 178, learning)
(178, 179, .)

(0, 2, We)
(3, 12, evaluated)
(13, 16, our)
(17, 23, method)
(24, 26, on)
(27, 32, three)
(33, 42, languages)
(43, 46, and)
(47, 55, obtained)
(56, 61, error)
(62, 67, rates)
(68, 70, of)
(71, 75, 0.27)
(76, 77, ‰)
(78, 79, ()
(79, 86, English)
(86, 87, ))
(87, 88, ,)
(89, 93, 0.35)
(94, 95, ‰)
(96, 97, ()
(97, 102, Dutch)
(102, 103, ))
(104, 107, and)
(108, 112, 0.76)
(113, 114, ‰)
(115, 116, ()
(116, 123, Italian)
(123, 124, ))
(125, 128, for)
(129, 132, our)
(133, 137, best)
(138, 144, models)
(144, 145, .)
```

The goal is to achieve two different data types:

- **`sents_with_positions`**: a list of list of tuples where the the tuples looks like each line of the textfile
- **`sents_words`**: a list of list of string made up of only the third element in the tuples from each line of the textfile

E.g. From the input textfile:

```
sents_words = [
    ('Tokenization', 'is', 'widely', 'regarded', 'as', 'a', 'solved',
     'problem', 'due', 'to', 'the', 'high', 'accuracy', 'that', 'rulebased',
     'tokenizers', 'achieve', '.'),
    ('But', 'rule-based', 'tokenizers', 'are', 'hard', 'to', 'maintain', 'and',
     'their', 'rules', 'language', 'specific', '.'),
    ('We', 'show', 'that', 'high', 'accuracy', 'word', 'and', 'sentence',
     'segmentation', 'can', 'be', 'achieved', 'by', 'using', 'supervised',
     'sequence', 'labeling', 'on', 'the', 'character', 'level', 'combined',
     'with', 'unsupervised', 'feature', 'learning', '.')
]

sents_with_positions = [
    [(0, 12, 'Tokenization'), (13, 15, 'is'), (16, 22, 'widely'),
     (23, 31, 'regarded'), (32, 34, 'as'), (35, 36, 'a'), (37, 43, 'solved'),
     (44, 51, 'problem'), (52, 55, 'due'), (56, 58, 'to'), (59, 62, 'the'),
     (63, 67, 'high'), (68, 76, 'accuracy'), (77, 81, 'that'),
     (82, 91, 'rulebased'), (92, 102, 'tokenizers'), (103, 110, 'achieve'),
     (110, 111, '.')],
    [(0, 3, 'But'), (4, 14, 'rule-based'), (15, 25, 'tokenizers'),
     (26, 29, 'are'), (30, 34, 'hard'), (35, 37, 'to'), (38, 46, 'maintain'),
     (47, 50, 'and'), (51, 56, 'their'), (57, 62, 'rules'),
     (63, 71, 'language'), (72, 80, 'specific'), (80, 81, '.')],
    [(0, 2, 'We'), (3, 7, 'show'), (8, 12, 'that'), (13, 17, 'high'),
     (18, 26, 'accuracy'), (27, 31, 'word'), (32, 35, 'and'),
     (36, 44, 'sentence'), (45, 57, 'segmentation'), (58, 61, 'can'),
     (62, 64, 'be'), (65, 73, 'achieved'), (74, 76, 'by'), (77, 82, 'using'),
     (83, 93, 'supervised'), (94, 102, 'sequence'), (103, 111, 'labeling'),
     (112, 114, 'on'), (115, 118, 'the'), (119, 128, 'character'),
     (129, 134, 'level'), (135, 143, 'combined'), (144, 148, 'with'),
     (149, 161, 'unsupervised'), (162, 169, 'feature'), (170, 178, 'learning'),
     (178, 179, '.')]
]
```

I have been doing it by:

- iterating through each line of the textfile, process the tuple, and then appending them to a list to get `sents_with_positions`
- and while appending each process sentence to `sents_with_positions`, I append the last elements of the tuples for each sentence to `sents_words`

Code:

```
sents_with_positions = []
sents_words = []
_sent = []
for line in _input.split('\n'):
    if len(line.strip()) > 0:
        line = line[1:-1]
        start, _, next = line.partition(',')
        end, _, next = next.partition(',')
        text = next.strip()
        _sent.append((int(start), int(end), text))
    else:
        sents_with_positions.append(_sent)
        sents_words.append(list(zip(*_sent))[2])
        _sent = []
```

**But is there a simpler way or cleaner way to do achieve the same output?** Maybe through regexes? Or some `itertools` trick?

Note that there are cases where there're tricky tuples in the lines of the textfile, e.g.

- `(86, 87, ))` # Sometimes the token/word is a bracket
- `(96, 97, ()`
- `(87, 88, ,)` # Sometimes the token/word is a comma
- `(29, 33, Café)` # The token/word is a unicode (sometimes accented), so [a-zA-Z] might be insufficient
- `(2, 3, 2)` # Sometimes the token/word is a number
- `(47, 52, 3,000)` # Sometimes the token/word is a number/word with comma
- `(23, 29, (e.g.))` # Someimtes the token/word contains bracket.

Comment: If you have working code that you think could be improved, consider [codereview.se]. If not, please clarify the issue.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, although it's not a matter of "why is the code broke and how to fix it" but it's more of "how to do this better and the code is somewhat overly 'verbose'". It's working code but this code seems to be overly processing the lines with multiple `str.partitions` and list appending.

Comment: Ok, so it's suited better to CR

Comment: @jonrsharpe noted =)

Comment: what should `(96, 97, ()` output?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I assume `(96, 97, '(')`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, `(96, 97, () ` should output `(96, 97, '(') `

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is, in my opinion, a little more readable and clear, but it may be a little less performant and assumes the input file is correctly formatted (e.g. empty lines are really empty, while your code works even if there is some random whitespace in the "empty" lines). It leverages regex groups, they do all the work of parsing the lines, we just convert start and end to integers.

```
line_regex = re.compile('^\((\d+), (\d+), (.+)\)$', re.MULTILINE)
sents_with_positions = []
sents_words = []

for section in _input.split('\n\n'):
    words_with_positions = [
        (int(start), int(end), text)
        for start, end, text in line_regex.findall(section)
    ]
    words = tuple(t[2] for t in words_with_positions)
    sents_with_positions.append(words_with_positions)
    sents_words.append(words)
```

Comment: Nice regex! Does it work for tricky tuples? `_input.split('\n\n')` assumes reading the whole file into memory. Is there a way to slice the data without loading into memory?

Comment: It works for tricky tuples, I tested in on your input and words consisting of `,` and `)` etc. are correctly recognized. Regarding not loading the entire file into memory, you just have to change the for loop using whatever method you want to subdivide the sections (for example using @unutbu's `open_chunk`  iterator), the code inside the for loop can then be left as-is.

Answer (score 5):

Parsing text files in chunks separated by some delimiter is a common problem. 
It helps to have a utility function, such as `open_chunk` below, which can "chunkify" text files given a regex delimiter. The `open_chunk` function yields chunks one at a time, without reading the whole file at once, so it can be used on files of any size. Once you've identified the chunks, processing each chunk is relatively easy:

```
import re

def open_chunk(readfunc, delimiter, chunksize=1024):
    """
    readfunc(chunksize) should return a string.
    http://stackoverflow.com/a/17508761/190597 (unutbu)        
    """
    remainder = ''
    for chunk in iter(lambda: readfunc(chunksize), ''):
        pieces = re.split(delimiter, remainder + chunk)
        for piece in pieces[:-1]:
            yield piece
        remainder = pieces[-1]
    if remainder:
        yield remainder

sents_with_positions = []
sents_words = []
with open('data') as infile:
    for chunk in open_chunk(infile.read, r'\n\n'):
        row = []
        words = []
        # Taken from LeartS's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34416814/190597
        for start, end, word in re.findall(
                r'\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(.*)\)', chunk, re.MULTILINE):
            start, end = int(start), int(end)
            row.append((start, end, word))
            words.append(word)
        sents_with_positions.append(row)
        sents_words.append(words)

print(sents_words)
print(sents_with_positions)
```

yields output which includes

```
(86, 87, ')'), (87, 88, ','), (96, 97, '(')
```

Comment: The `open_chunk` is interesting, nice!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using python 3 and you don't mind `(87, 88, ,)` becoming `('87', '88', '')`, you can use `csv.reader` to parse the values removing the outer `()` by slicing:

```
from itertools import groupby
from csv import reader

def yield_secs(fle):
    with open(fle) as f:
        for k, v in groupby(map(str.rstrip, f), key=lambda x: x.strip() != ""):
            if k:
                tmp1, tmp2 = [], []
                for t in v:
                    a, b, c, *_ = next(reader([t[1:-1]], skipinitialspace=True))
                    tmp1.append((a,b,c))
                    tmp2.append(c)
                yield tmp1, tmp2


for sec in yield_secs("test.txt"):
    print(sec)
```

You can fix the with  `if not c:c = ","` as the only way it will be an empty string is if it is a `,` so you will get `('87', '88', ',')`.

For python2 you just need to slice the first three elements to avoid an unpack error:

```
from itertools import groupby, imap


def yield_secs(fle):
    with open(fle) as f:
        for k, v in groupby(imap(str.rstrip, f), key=lambda x: x.strip() != ""):
            if k:
                tmp1, tmp2 = [], []
                for t in v:
                    t  = next(reader([t[1:-1]], skipinitialspace=True))
                    tmp1.append(tuple(t[:3]))
                    tmp2.append(t[0])
                yield tmp1, tmp2
```

If you want all the data at once:

```
def yield_secs(fle):
    with open(fle) as f:
        sent_word, sent_with_position = [], []
        for k, v in groupby(map(str.rstrip, f), key=lambda x: x.strip() != ""):
            if k:
                tmp1, tmp2 = [], []
                for t in v:
                    a, b, c, *_ = next(reader([t[1:-1]], skipinitialspace=True))
                    tmp1.append((a, b, c))
                    tmp2.append(c)
                sent_word.append(tmp2)
                sent_with_position.append(tmp1)
    return sent_word, sent_with_position


sent, sent_word = yield_secs("test.txt")
```

You can actually do it by just splitting also and keep any comma as it can only appear at the end so `t[1:-1].split(", ")` will only split on the first two commas:

```
def yield_secs(fle):
    with open(fle) as f:
        sent_word, sent_with_position = [], []
        for k, v in groupby(map(str.rstrip, f), key=lambda x: x.strip() != ""):
            if k:
                tmp1, tmp2 = [], []
                for t in v:
                    a, b, c, *_ =  t[1:-1].split(", ")
                    tmp1.append((a, b, c))
                    tmp2.append(c)
                sent_word.append(tmp2)
                sent_with_position.append(tmp1)
    return sent_word, sent_with_position

snt, snt_pos = (yield_secs())

from pprint import pprint
pprint(snt)
pprint(snt_pos)
```

Which will give you:

```
[['Tokenization',
  'is',
  'widely',
  'regarded',
  'as',
  'a',
  'solved',
  'problem',
  'due',
  'to',
  'the',
  'high',
  'accuracy',
  'that',
  'rulebased',
  'tokenizers',
  'achieve',
  '.'],
 ['But',
  'rule-based',
  'tokenizers',
  'are',
  'hard',
  'to',
  'maintain',
  'and',
  'their',
  'rules',
  'language',
  'specific',
  '.'],
 ['We',
  'show',
  'that',
  'high',
  'accuracy',
  'word',
  'and',
  'sentence',
  'segmentation',
  'can',
  'be',
  'achieved',
  'by',
  'using',
  'supervised',
  'sequence',
  'labeling',
  'on',
  'the',
  'character',
  'level',
  'combined',
  'with',
  'unsupervised',
  'feature',
  'learning',
  '.'],
 ['We',
  'evaluated',
  'our',
  'method',
  'on',
  'three',
  'languages',
  'and',
  'obtained',
  'error',
  'rates',
  'of',
  '0.27',
  '‰',
  '(',
  'English',
  ')',
  ',',
  '0.35',
  '‰',
  '(',
  'Dutch',
  ')',
  'and',
  '0.76',
  '‰',
  '(',
  'Italian',
  ')',
  'for',
  'our',
  'best',
  'models',
  '.']]
[[('0', '12', 'Tokenization'),
  ('13', '15', 'is'),
  ('16', '22', 'widely'),
  ('23', '31', 'regarded'),
  ('32', '34', 'as'),
  ('35', '36', 'a'),
  ('37', '43', 'solved'),
  ('44', '51', 'problem'),
  ('52', '55', 'due'),
  ('56', '58', 'to'),
  ('59', '62', 'the'),
  ('63', '67', 'high'),
  ('68', '76', 'accuracy'),
  ('77', '81', 'that'),
  ('82', '91', 'rulebased'),
  ('92', '102', 'tokenizers'),
  ('103', '110', 'achieve'),
  ('110', '111', '.')],
 [('0', '3', 'But'),
  ('4', '14', 'rule-based'),
  ('15', '25', 'tokenizers'),
  ('26', '29', 'are'),
  ('30', '34', 'hard'),
  ('35', '37', 'to'),
  ('38', '46', 'maintain'),
  ('47', '50', 'and'),
  ('51', '56', 'their'),
  ('57', '62', 'rules'),
  ('63', '71', 'language'),
  ('72', '80', 'specific'),
  ('80', '81', '.')],
 [('0', '2', 'We'),
  ('3', '7', 'show'),
  ('8', '12', 'that'),
  ('13', '17', 'high'),
  ('18', '26', 'accuracy'),
  ('27', '31', 'word'),
  ('32', '35', 'and'),
  ('36', '44', 'sentence'),
  ('45', '57', 'segmentation'),
  ('58', '61', 'can'),
  ('62', '64', 'be'),
  ('65', '73', 'achieved'),
  ('74', '76', 'by'),
  ('77', '82', 'using'),
  ('83', '93', 'supervised'),
  ('94', '102', 'sequence'),
  ('103', '111', 'labeling'),
  ('112', '114', 'on'),
  ('115', '118', 'the'),
  ('119', '128', 'character'),
  ('129', '134', 'level'),
  ('135', '143', 'combined'),
  ('144', '148', 'with'),
  ('149', '161', 'unsupervised'),
  ('162', '169', 'feature'),
  ('170', '178', 'learning'),
  ('178', '179', '.')],
 [('0', '2', 'We'),
  ('3', '12', 'evaluated'),
  ('13', '16', 'our'),
  ('17', '23', 'method'),
  ('24', '26', 'on'),
  ('27', '32', 'three'),
  ('33', '42', 'languages'),
  ('43', '46', 'and'),
  ('47', '55', 'obtained'),
  ('56', '61', 'error'),
  ('62', '67', 'rates'),
  ('68', '70', 'of'),
  ('71', '75', '0.27'),
  ('76', '77', '‰'),
  ('78', '79', '('),
  ('79', '86', 'English'),
  ('86', '87', ')'),
  ('87', '88', ','),
  ('89', '93', '0.35'),
  ('94', '95', '‰'),
  ('96', '97', '('),
  ('97', '102', 'Dutch'),
  ('102', '103', ')'),
  ('104', '107', 'and'),
  ('108', '112', '0.76'),
  ('113', '114', '‰'),
  ('115', '116', '('),
  ('116', '123', 'Italian'),
  ('123', '124', ')'),
  ('125', '128', 'for'),
  ('129', '132', 'our'),
  ('133', '137', 'best'),
  ('138', '144', 'models'),
  ('144', '145', '.')]]
```

Comment: @unutbu, actually what would be a correct value as it is a bit like an empty column?

Comment: Judging from the OP's code (in particular, the `str.partition` calls), I think the desired output is `(87, 88, ',')`.

Comment: @unutbu,  just splitting on `", "` should actually do the job as the comma has to be at the end if anywhere and the format of the tuples should always be the same

Comment: Yes, that would work. Come to think of it, `split(',', 2)` should work too.

Comment: @unutbu, yep, better again

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex and `deque` which is more optimized when you are dealing with huge files:

```
import re
from collections import deque

sents_with_positions = deque()
container = deque()

with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line != '\n':
            try:
                matched_tuple = re.search(r'^\((\d+),\s?(\d+),\s?(.*)\)\n$',line).groups()
            except AttributeError:
                pass
            else:
                container.append(matched_tuple)
        else:
            sents_with_positions.append(container)
            container.clear()
```

Comment: How different is the line regex from @LeartS?

Answer (score 2):

I've read many good answers, some of them using approaches next to what i've used when i read the question. Anyway i think i've added something to the subject so i've decided to post.

**Abstract**

My solution is based on a `single line` parsing approach to handle files that won't easily fit in memory.

The line decodification is made by an `unicode-aware regex`. It parses both lines with data and empty ones to be aware of the end of current section. This made the parsing process `os-agnostic` in spite of the specific line-separator (`\n`, `\r`, `\r\n`).

Just to be sure (when handling big files you can never know) i've also added `fault-tolerance` to exceeding spaces or tabs in the input data.

**e.g.** lines such as: `( 0   ,  4,  röck  )` or `( 86, 87 ,  ))` are both parsed correctly (see more below in the *regex breakout* section and the output of the online [demo](http://ideone.com/qmO3O7)).

**Code Snippet**    <kbd>[Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/qmO3O7)</kbd>

```py
import re

words = []
positions = []

pattern = re.compile(ur'^
(?:
  [ \t]*[(][ \t]*
  (\d+)
  [ \t]*,[ \t]*
  (\d+)
  [ \t]*,[ \t]*
  (\S+)
  [ \t]*[)][ \t]*
)?
$', re.UNICODE | re.VERBOSE)

w_buffer = []
p_buffer = []    
# automatically close the file handler also in case of exception
with open('file.input') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        for (start, end, token) in re.findall(pattern, line):
            if start:
                w_buffer.append(token)
                p_buffer.append((int(start), int(end), token))
            else:
                words.append(tuple(w_buffer)); w_buffer = []
                positions.append(p_buffer); p_buffer = []
    if start:
        words.append(tuple(w_buffer))
        positions.append(p_buffer)

# An optional prettified output
import pprint as pp
pp.pprint(words)
pp.pprint(positions)
```

**Regex Breakout**   <kbd>[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kO1cK7/2)</kbd>

[image: Regular expression visualization]

```
^                   # Start of the string
(?:                 # Start NCG1 (Non Capturing Group 1)
  [ \t]* [(] [ \t]* # (1): A literal opening round bracket (i prefer over '\(')...
                    # ...surrounded by zero or more spaces or tabs
  (\d+)             # One or more digits ([0-9]+) saved in CG1 (Capturing Group 1)
                    #
  [ \t]*  ,  [ \t]* # (2) A literal comma ','...
                    # ...surrounded by zero or more spaces or tabs
  (\d+)             # One or more digits ([0-9]+) saved in CG2
                    #
  [ \t]*  ,  [ \t]* # see (2)
                    #
  (\S+)             # One or more of any non-whitespace character... 
                    # ...(as [^\s]) saved in CG3
  [ \t]* [)] [ \t]* # see (1)
)?                  # Close NCG1, '?' makes group optional...
                    # ...to match also empty lines (as '^$')
$                   # End of the string (with or without newline)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this a good challenge to do in a single replace regex.

I got the first part of your Q working leaving out some edge cases and stripping away non essential details.

Below is a screenshot of how far I got using the excellent RegexBuddy tool.

Do you want a pure regex solution as this or look for solutions which use code to process intermediate regex results.

If you are looking for a pure regex solution I don't mind spending more time on to cater for the details.

[image]

Comment: If a pure regex solution is possible then that'll be a real great feat!

Comment: @alvas The gist of the pure regex solution is already there. I'll complete the details if this is the preferred solution of all. Its more of an intellectual challenge as some imperative code around regexes is arguably more readable.

Comment: If the pure regex solution is possible. I would allocate the bounty to that but the checkmark will go to something more maintainable ;P I would really like to see how the regex only solution would work. It sounds feasible since it's basically finding groups of the regex you already have in the screenshot. But please do take care of the edge tricky cases as shown in the OP =)

Answer (score 0):

Each line of the text looks similar to a tuple. If the last components of the tuples were quoted, they could be `eval`d. That's exactly what I've done, quoting the last component.

```
from itertools import takewhile, repeat, dropwhile
from functools import partial

def quote_last(line):
    line = line.split(',',2)
    last = line[-1].strip()
    if '"' in last:
        last = last.replace('"',r'\"')
    return eval('{0[0]}, {0[1]}, "{1}")'.format(line, last[:-1]))

skip_leading_empty_lines_if_any = partial(dropwhile, lambda line: not line.strip())
get_lines_between_empty_lines = partial(takewhile, lambda line: line.strip())
get_non_empty_lists = partial(takewhile, bool)

def get_tuples(lines):
    #non_empty_lines = takewhile(bool, (list(lst) for lst in (takewhile(lambda s: s.strip(), dropwhile(lambda x: not bool(x.strip()), it)) for it in repeat(iter(lines)))))

    list_of_non_empty_lines = get_non_empty_lists(list(lst) for lst in (get_lines_between_empty_lines(
                        skip_leading_empty_lines_if_any(it)) for it in repeat(iter(lines))))

    return [[quote_last(line) for line in lst] for lst in list_of_non_empty_lines]


sents_with_positions = get_tuples(lines)
sents_words  = [[t[-1] for t in lst] for lst in sents_with_positions]
```

Comment: what happens when there's lines like `(83, 84, ")` or `(83, 84, ')`?

Comment: @alvas `(83, 84, ")` or `(83, 84, ')` become `(83, 84, '"')` or `(83, 84, "'")`. That's they're simply quoted.